# Using a field selected in one select statement in another select statement?

Tags: sql, select, join

I have this query, and need to add a new field to it. I could either do a bunch of joins to get the field, but would rather join once and then use the field in all of the other select statements. Below is the query:

```
select
  BCCR.DocumentNumber
  , BCCR.BCCRDebitMemo
  , BCCR.BCCRDate
  , BCCR.RejectFlag
  , BCCR.ManualEntry
  , BCCR.DebitTotal
  , coalesce(BCCRApproved.BCCRAmount,0) BCCRAmount
  , coalesce(BCCRRejected.BCCRRejectedAmount,0) BCCRRejectedAmount
  , coalesce(BCCRRejected.BCCRRejectedLines,0) BCCRRejectedLines
from
(select
  h.DocumentNumber
  , h.DebitMemo as BCCRDebitMemo
  , h.TransmissionDate as BCCRDate
  , 'N' RejectFlag
  , h.ManualEntry
  , h.DebitTotal
from chargebackheader h 
where h.TransmissionDate >= @BeginDate
and h.TransmissionDate <= @EndDate) BCCR left join
(select
  h.DocumentNumber
  , ROUND(SUM(d.ChargebackAmount),2) as BCCRAmount
from chargebackheader h join chargebackdetail d on
  h.DocumentBranchPlant=d.DocumentBranchPlant
  and h.DocumentNumber=d.DocumentNumber
  and h.DocumentType=d.DocumentType
where h.TransmissionDate >= @BeginDate
and h.TransmissionDate <= @EndDate
and d.RejectFlag = 'N'
group by
  h.DocumentNumber
  , h.DebitMemo
  , h.TransmissionDate
  , h.ManualEntry
  , h.DebitTotal) BCCRApproved on BCCR.DocumentNumber = BCCRApproved.DocumentNumber
```

So say I wanted to add a processeddate field to the second BCCR select statement. I could do a join there. I also need to add this field to the third select statement. Could I take the field from the second statement and add it to the third statement without having to redo the joins in the third statement?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you want to use a stored procedure.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792(v=sql.80).aspx

Then you can simply `DECLARE` variables and `SELECT` results into them.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/03/18/sql-server-2008-2011-declare-and-assign-variable-in-single-statement/

Once you have assigned the variable, you may use it as you please within the scope of the stored procedure.

Comment: so follow the second link, `SELECT` a result into a variable and simply use that variable.